# My computer becomes paralyzed at times

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, resource-monitor

My computer(Toshiba L55C, 2.2 GHz, 8 GB, 64 bit) running W10 regularly goes into paralysis.  I ran a complete reinstallation of W10, and I still have the problem. Using Resource Monitor to terminate all Chrome activity often helps - but instead of being paralyzed for 5 minutes, it sometimes recovers within 30 seconds.  Norton 360 doesn't see anything wrong, and I have uninstalled as much bloatware as I can identify. I also am surprise that there are 78 instances of scvhost (or some variation) running when the only programs open are Thunderbird, Microsoft Edge and Resource Monitor

Comment: I erred if I mentioned Firefox - I do have Thunderbird, but not Firefox. However, I have apparently solved the problem by doing an "out of the box" reinstallation of W10.  This has taken considerable time, but so far, things seem OK

Answer (score 1):

[svchost.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svchost.exe) usually runs any time something is calling the Global Assembly Cache libraries, and is alone not very meaningful.  I wouldn't trust Norton, though.  Norton is one of the most common antivirus and antimalware suites, so malware authors specifically target it and try to either infect it or bypass it.  It also won't go scouring through your browser cache, and many AV suites won't do that anyway.

More than once, I've found something nasty hiding in Google's cache files.  Killing all instances of Chrome and wiping out all saved passwords, cookies, and internet history often solves problems like the one you're experiencing.  If this makes a significant difference, you need to set up a boot-time scan of some sort with an AV suite that will scan for rootkits; malware that loads itself on startup is often completely overlooked unless you scan for it before it gets a chance to run.

Comment: Do you have HDD or SSD? It could be your hard drive is failing - do a S.M.A.R.T test on it, and monitor disk activity light when it's unresponsive.

Comment: I finally did a complete "out of the box" reset of W10.  Things are better so far.  Thanks for the information - I will keep this for reference in case of future problems.  I have also aggressively deleted any bloatware or other apps I don't need - as soon as W10 reinstalled.   The computer is pretty clean at the moment